# What data structure should I use in Python to represent a preflop tree in Poker - NL Texas Holdem?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I am trying to model preflop play of NL Texas Holdem and store corresponding ranges/actions in Python.

It is often referred to colloquially in videos as "in this branch of the tree..." (for lets say player on the Button facing 3-bet from Big Bling).
So I thought a tree would be appropriate.

But the problem is that in a tree branches have no value, that is "Facing 3-Bet from the Button" is just a "child" of "Big Blind 3-bets", but in the scenario that I am trying to model "Facing 3-Bet from the Button" is different if the Big Blind bets 9, 12 or 15 big blinds.

How should I model that?

The second problem is than comparing similar situations preflop.
If any action taken by player leads to another sub-node than similar situations preflop reside on different depths or levels of the tree and are not really comparable.

For example:
LJ (Seat 1) folds, HJ (Seat 2) folds, CO (Seat 3) folds, Button is facing unopened pot ---> level 4

LJ (Seat 1) raises first in, HJ (Seat 2) raises/3-bets, LJ (Seat 1) raises all in, HJ (Seat 2) is facing all-in bet ---> level 4

So both are reached after 4-actions although the scenarios could not be more apart. Makes it difficult to compare between similar situations. How should I go about it?

Comment: a tree, maybe...

Comment: I am suggesting that in 2nd paragraph and explaining why I think it might not be enough or appropriate. So I would appreciate either tree WITH *** what I am missing *** or SOMETHING ELSE.